# Spring Boot Post Mapping With WebSecurity

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, spring-security

I am a complete noob in Spirng Boot, but I tried to create a login page with "WebSecurity". I connected with a "Postgresql" databse, is working the application is running, but I do not know how I should connect, because I have my registration class:

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/registration")
public class RegistrationController {

    private RegistrationService registrationService;
    @PostMapping
    public String register(@RequestBody RegistrationRequest request){

        return registrationService.register(request);
    }
}
```

The "RegistrationService" class:

```
@Service
public class RegistrationService {

    public String register(RegistrationRequest request) {
        return "it works";
    }
}
```

And as it below the path is "api/v1/registration". I have tried to do my security configuration first but a lot of things are deprecated unfortunately and I kind of stuck now because I do not know what should I do. I do not know if I used "@Bean" correctly there, by the way.
This is the security class:

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final AppUserServices appUserServices;

    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/v*/registration/**")
                    .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin();

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
```

I have tried to use "PostMan" in order to send a "Post" to the registration and instead of getting the "it works" message back I receive the web page with the login portal, as it is showing in the next image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t98iE.png)

Comment: Your code has a line                     .requestMatchers("/api/v*/registration/**")
. Change to                     .requestMatchers("/api/v1/registration") to see if the wildcards are the issue. Then we think about next move.

Comment: @JohnWilliams nope is still the same thing.

Comment: That’s different. Is it a 415? We may be making progress. Is your postman body set to raw and json with a valid json body? Add you postman curl to the question - it’s under the ‘</>’ on the right.

Comment: @JohnWilliams I am using raw not Json

Comment: Try json with valid json body. Also, add your postman curl to the question - it’s under the ‘</>’ on the right.

Comment: I am so sorry, I did not know, thank you so much! Should I delete this post?

Comment: No need to delete. Just set the body raw json in postman and see if it works.

Comment: Just change “Text” to JSON on the drop-down above the Request Body as shown in the image you included in the question.